# JSON to Excel using Openpyxyl - Convert Complex/Nested Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, json, excel, openpyxl

I'm new to JSON and arrays/lists things. I'm trying to put this JSON file in an Excel file:

```
{
  "__collections__": {
    "users": {
      "a12jh2d53622146fj": {
        "age": "19",
        "location": "USA"
      },
      "agHSHnAp363mqo125": {
        "age": "4865",
        "location": "UK"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code that I've been working on:

```
import json
from openpyxl import Workbook

if __name__ == '__main__':

    json_data = {}

    with open("Test.json") as json_file:
        json_data = json.load(json_file)

    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    ws.title = "Test"

    ws.cell(1,1, "User ID")
    ws.cell(1,2, "Age")
    ws.cell(1,3, "Location")

    row = 1

    for userID in json_data.keys():
        row += 1
        ws.cell(row,1, userID)
        ws.cell(row,2, str(json_data[userID]["age"]))
        ws.cell(row,3, str(json_data[userID]["location"]))
        
    wb.save("Test.xlsx")
```

Unfortunately, the above code only works if the JSON file is like this:

```
{
  "a12jh2d53622146fj": {
    "age": "19",
    "location": "USA"
  },
  "agHSHnAp363mqo125": {
    "age": "4865",
    "location": "UK"
  }
}
```

This is the output excel file:

[image: This is the output excel file.]

Cheers!

Comment: You say _"Unfortunately, it only works if I delete these lines"_,
this doesn't help. What does help is when you show what happens -
what goes wrong - when you run the code you've posted. That means
including the full stack trace if you're getting a python error.

Comment: When I run your code I get **KeyError: 'age'**, you need to start investigating from there. What's happening is that you're iterating on `json_data` (that has a single key `__collections__`), you should iterate on `json_data['__collections__']['users']`

Comment: Hey @joao, thanks for helping! It worked with this code.

`for userID in json_data['__collections__']['users'].keys():`